# How can i create a c# method that will return the same collection type as as argument with a different element type?

Tags: c#, generics

essentially, exactly as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089432/how-can-i-return-the-same-collection-type-given-as-a-parameter-but-with-a-diffe), but in c#.

I want to have something like this:

```
public IList<double> DoSomething(IList<string> strings) {
    //something
}
```

But i'd rather have it typed such that the return value is known ahead of time so that i don't have to cast or anything outside the function. How do i do this?

Is there a generic way,

```
public ListType<double> DoSomething<ListType>(ListType<string> strings) where ListType : ???{
```

to set this up?

Comment: You can use Linq to do this.

Comment: @EricLinde can you show me in an answer? And does it deal with the issue of the return collection type matching the input collection type?

Answer (score 2):

C# does not allow exactly what you want, but the closest thing would be:

```
public TList2 DoSomething<TList1, TList2>(TList1 strings) 
    where TList1 : IEnumerable<string>
    where TList2 : ICollection<decimal>, new()
{
    var result = new TList2();
    foreach (var s in strings)
    {
        result.Add(decimal.Parse(s));
    }
    return result;
}
```

and an example:

```
var input = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "1", "2", "3"});
List<decimal> output = DoSomething<HashSet<string>, List<decimal>>(input);
```

Comment: This is what i feared. So there's no way i can force them to be the same collection type without resorting to runtime checks?

Comment: Why do you need them to be?  How are you using the input so that it needs to be some vague (but generic) collection type?  Why not just use `IEnumerable<string>` as the input type?

Comment: It's more that i wanted it to be consistent with whatever the input is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to do this.

For instance if you just want to parse to double you would do:

```
List<double> result = strings.Select(double.Parse).ToList()
```

And you can send in any other method instead of double.Parse:

```
List<double> result = strings.Select(DoSomethingWithOneItem).ToList()

double DoSomethingWithOneItem(string item) {
  //your conversion logic
}
```

Unfortunately there is no relation between for instance `IList<TInput>` and `IList<TOutput>` that can be used to help here, so you will need to specify both the input and output list type, which becomes a bit cumbersome in the general form:

```
IList<string> strings  = new List<string> {"1.1", "2.2", "3.3"};
IList<decimal> result = strings.ConvertToSameListType((Func<string, decimal>)decimal.Parse, () => new List<decimal>());

public static class EnumerableExtensioncGeneralVersion
{
    public static TOutputList ConvertToSameListType<TInputList, TOutputList, TInput, TOutput>(this TInputList source, Func<TInput, TOutput> itemConversion, Func<TOutputList> outputListConstructor)
        where TInputList : IEnumerable<TInput>
        where TOutputList : ICollection<TOutput>
    {
        TOutputList result = outputListConstructor();
        foreach (TOutput convertedItem in source.Select(itemConversion))
        {
            result.Add(convertedItem);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Though you can make it much nicer to use your conversions if you just specify one extension method for each of your favourite collection types that you want to support:

```
//Seting up inputs
IList<string> strings  = new List<string> {"1.1", "2.2", "3.3"};
IEnumerable<string> enumerableStrings = strings.Select(x => x);
ObservableCollection<string> observableStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>(strings);

//Converting
IList<decimal> resultList = strings.Convert(decimal.Parse);
IEnumerable<decimal> resultEnumerable = enumerableStrings.Convert(decimal.Parse);
ObservableCollection<decimal> observableResult = observableStrings.Convert(decimal.Parse);

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IList<TOutput> Convert<TInput, TOutput>(this IList<TInput> source, Func<TInput, TOutput> itemConversion)
    {
        return source.Select(itemConversion).ToList();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<TOutput> Convert<TInput, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source, Func<TInput, TOutput> itemConversion)
    {
        return source.Select(itemConversion);
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<TOutput> Convert<TInput, TOutput>(this ObservableCollection<TInput> source, Func<TInput, TOutput> itemConversion)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<TOutput>(source.Select(itemConversion));
    }
}
```

Comment: This means i need to do it every time i want to use it though. I want something more like in [felix-b's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38333974/432913).

Comment: To my understanding, the question was about specifying concrete type of collection in generic parameters of a method, and not about transforming one collection into another.

Comment: Yep if you want your output List type to always match your input list type then you need something more like what @felix-b suggests

Comment: @EricLinde what felix has does not enforce they match, it just allows you to define the input and the output types (though i don't know why the input type is needed).

Comment: Updated my answer now with something that hopefully is closer to what you need.

Comment: Hey, obviously just creating a version of the function for each collection type would work - this is the opposite of generic though.

Comment: Yep true - though from a pragmatic standpoint it's mostly a matter of deciding whether the generic version is nicer (write the method once and a little more cumbersone to call) or the less generic version (write a handful of methods that are a bit easier to call)